# How to highlight the rows and columns in the output file?

Tags: excel, python-3.10

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

def find(wb, string):
res = []
for ws in wb:
    for row in ws.values:
        for value in row:
            if value is not None and string in 
str(value):
                res.append(value)
return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
wb = load_workbook("C:\Book1.xlsx")
values = find(wb, "NAS019")

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for value in values:
    ws.append([value])
wb.save(filename="C:\Book2.xlsx")
```

Basically, I just want the output file to have highlighted rows and columns. So, when you open the output file all the information should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ws.cell(row+1, 1).fill` along with the append to add colors to the cell you are updating. `Patternfill` in openpyxl allows you to set cell background color. The updated code is below.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

def find(wb, string):
    res = []
    for ws in wb:
        for row in ws.values:
            for value in row:
                if value is not None and string in str(value):
                    res.append(value)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    wb = load_workbook("C:\Book1.xlsx")
    values = find(wb, "NAS019")
    print(values)
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill ## Import library
    fillColor = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid') ##I have set the color to yellow, you can change as you need
    for row, value in enumerate(values):
        ws.append([value])
        ws.cell(row+1, 1).fill = fillColor ##Set the color of cell
    wb.save(filename="C:\Book2.xlsx")
```